# On semi-direct product of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product

If for two finite groups $G$ and $H$ we have $G/N \cong H$, where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, can we say $G\cong NH$ as a semidirect product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $G$ cyclic of order $4$ and $H \leq G$ subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: Thanks. What other conditions are necessary for the statement mentioned in the question to be true?

Comment: $G$ should contain a subgroup $K \cong H$ such that $K \cap N = 1$.

Comment: @user97635 :if $gcd(|N|,|G:N|)=1$ then it is true.it is known as Schur–Zassenhaus theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem